# "provided" conf ivy dependencies not used in build

Tags: java, netbeans, build, ant, ivy

I am using Netbeans to build a web application (with Tomcat & Java).

I use Ant for the build and Ivy for dependency management.

Previously, I did not set the `conf` attribute on the dependencies and just included them all in my `WEB-INF/lib` folder.
Now, I would like certain `JARs` to only be used for compiling and not be bundled with my application (ie: 'provided' scope): `servlet-api.jar`, `el-api.jar`, `jsp-api.jar`.

As a result, I added the `conf` attribute to the dependency elements in my `ivy.xml` as well as adding `configurations` as follows:

```
    <configurations>
        <conf name="compile"  description="Required to compile application" 
              visibility="public"/>
        <conf name="runtime"  description="Additional run-time dependencies" 
              visibility="public" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test"     description="Required for test only" 
              visibility="public" extends="runtime"/>
        <conf name="provided" description="Needed for compile, but will be present on the target platform." 
              visibility="public"/>
    </configurations>.

    <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
            <dependency org="javax.servlet" name="javax.servlet-api" rev="3.1.0"
                        conf="provided->master"/>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/javax.el-api -->
            <dependency org="javax.el" name="javax.el-api" rev="3.0.1-b06" 
                        conf="provided->master"/>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
            <dependency org="javax.servlet.jsp" name="javax.servlet.jsp-api" rev="2.3.3" 
                        conf="provided->master"/>
    </dependencies>
```

I'm leaving out all the "regular" dependencies from the code above where I didn't specify a `conf` as they are to be included for compiling and for runtime.

I call a task in order to resolve and retrieve the runtime JARs and place them in my application's WEB-INF/lib like so:

```
<target name="-ivy-retrieve">
        <ivy:resolve/>
        
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile,provided"/>
        
        <ivy:retrieve sync="true" conf="runtime"/> <!-- Load dependencies to the project -->
        <pathconvert property="ivy.classpath.computed" dirsep="/" pathsep=":">
            <path>
                <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
            </path>
            <map from="${basedir}${file.separator}" to=""/>
        </pathconvert>
        <propertyfile file="nbproject/project.properties">
            <entry operation="=" key="ivy.classpath" value="${ivy.classpath.computed}"/>
        </propertyfile>
    </target>
    <target name="-pre-compile" depends="-ivy-retrieve"/>
    <target name="-pre-compile-single" depends="-ivy-retrieve"/>
    <target name="-post-clean">
        <delete dir="lib"/>
    </target>
```

This pulls the necessary JARs into my WEB-INF/lib.

I am able to deploy. However, I'm not sure how to integrate the `compile.path` `cachepath` into my build so that these `JARs` (ie: `serlvet-api.jar`, `el-api.jar`, `jsp-api.jar`) are available for compiling.
As a result, I get a whole bunch of log Errors after deploying (which I think indicates that these `JARs` were not available during compiling).

I found a compile target in `build-impl.xml`:

```
<target depends="init, deps-jar, -pre-pre-compile, -pre-compile, -copy-manifest, -copy-persistence-xml, -copy-webdir, library-inclusion-in-archive,library-inclusion-in-manifest" if="have.sources" name="-do-compile">
        <webproject2:javac destdir="${build.classes.dir}" gensrcdir="${build.generated.sources.dir}"/>
        <copy todir="${build.classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="${build.classes.excludes},${excludes}" includes="${includes}"/>
        </copy>
    </target>
```

However, I'm not quite certain how to set the classpath for this target (I tried adding a `classpathref` attribute to the `webproject:javac` element, but this caused an error as this attribute is not recognized there).

I also tried defining the classpath in a separate element like so:

```
<classpath refid="compile.path" />
```

Immediately following the `webproject2:javac` line but this also yields an error

> Problem: failed to create task or type classpath Cause: The name is
> undefined.

Please explain how to adjust my build so that the `provided` `conf` dependencies will be used correctly.